# How do I create extensionless urls with my htaccess file that looks like this?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, markup

Im trying to create extension-less urls on my site and have a few questions.  Hopefully, someone can help me.

Here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

1. This code adds the trailing slash whether you add it or not.  Is it better to have the trailing slash or without? Or does it matter? The next 2 questions are dependent on what's the best option for question #1.
2. When writing the markup which is a better way to write it? `http://www.mysite.com/test` or `http://www.mysite.com/test/`
3. If I have an index.html file in the Folder "Test" and other files in the same folder will the trailing slash on the non index.html files with that file trump all others?  I'm assuming it will.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Use the trailing slash.
http://www.searchenginejournal.com/linking-issues-why-a-trailing-slash-in-the-url-does-matter/13021/

So you should write the url as www.mysite.com/test/

On to your last question. I personally would use directories to get rid of trailing slashes. For your example url for instance I would create a directory `test` and add an index.html file in that directory. Then navigating the browser to http://www.mysite.com/test/ would take you to that page. An added benefit is that you can add a custom .htaccess file in that directory.

Are you having an specific problem with your rewrite rules as they are that I missed?

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Ivan.  I appreciate you taking the time to answer.  So if I do put an index.html in the folder and that folder ha subcategories for example.  "Test" is the folder and i have categories test1.html, test2.html etc. would i still write the link as http://www.mysite.com/test/test1/ and http://www.mysite.com/test/test2/? I would really hate to ask how to write another htaccess file for that folder.  Its already confusing enough to me :)

Comment: If you wanted to go deeper you would continue creating directories. So in your example /test/ you could create a directory inside your test directory called /test2/ and place an index file in that. To navigate to that directory the url would be www.site.com/test/test2/. You wouldn't need an .htaccess file for those directories, but if you wanted to do something special you could add one.